# How do you make c# ask for a confirmation?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I can't figure out how to make it so that if I ask my C# voice application, "Call Mark" It will ask for a confirmation and only call him if I say "Yes".

```
case "Call Mark:
    speak.SpeakAsync("Are you sure");

        break;
```

I would guess that I would have to use a Bool, but I don't know how without making it so that I have to say "yes" before you say "call Mark." Another way that I tried just made it so that when I said "yes" it would call him.

Comment: Just have the `speak.SpeakAsync` return a bool. Then check that value before you actually make the call.

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but I'd have doubts about hardcoding all possible commands into a switch statement... apart from testing anyway.

Comment: @DangerZone How would you do it otherwise?

Comment: @ScottGibbard - I really can't tell you, because I don't know enough about your code or even app, but think about a cell phone with voice recognition where someone can call any contact by name... You couldn't possibly add a case for every single name/nickname the user could possibly say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll express my answer using the high-level algorithm, for clarity.

1. Wait to receive "Call Mark"
2. Speak "Are you sure?"
3. If the answer is "yes", then call Mark.

In code:

```
if (speech = "CALL MARK) {
    var string input = Api.DetectSpeech(Source.Microphone);
    if (input = "YES") {
        Phone.DialNumber(Contacts.Mark);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ScottGibbard:  Sure thing.  Please see the added code.

Comment: I have encountered two problems. 1.) There is no "DetectSpeech." 2.) It says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool.' Can you please tell me how to fix them? Otherwise, thanks!

Comment: Hm.  Sorry. It looks like I was looking at the wrong documentation.  I don't have any info on this api.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have the `.SpeakAsync()` method return a bool. Then you would check the result before actually making the call.

```
case "Call Mark":
    bool confirmationResult = speak.SpeakAsync("Are you sure");
    if (confirmationResult)
        MakeCall();
    break;
```

Comment: That worked except that `speak.SpeakAsync("Are you sure");` got an error that says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Speech.Synthesis.Prompt' to 'bool.'"

Comment: If the `SpeakAsync()` method is from a third party library you will have to leverage this idea from what the library offers.